# Nativescript Sidekick does not see my iPad Mini 2

Tags: ios, ipad, nativescript, sidekick

I can't get Sidekick to see my iPad Mini device. iTunes can see it and my computer recognizes it. I've tried multiple USB ports. When I enter the command "tns devices" in the terminal it says "iTunes isn't installed" even though it is. I was on Linux originally but discovered on the github that this was a known issue. So I am now on Windows 10 but still having the same problem. Has anyone got this working on Windows?